# Regular expression to print a string from a command outpout

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a function that uses regex and prints the required string from a command output.
The script works as expected. But it's does not support a dynamic output. currently, I use regex for "icmp" and "ok" and print the values. Now, `type` , `destination` and `return code` could change. There is a high chance that command doesn't return an output at all.  How do I handle such scenarios ?

```
sub check_summary{

    my ($self) = @_;

    my $type  = 0;
    my $return_type = 0;

    my $ipsla = $self->{'ssh_obj'}->exec('show ip sla');

    foreach my $line( $ipsla) {
    if ( $line =~ m/(icmp)/ ) {
            $type = $1;
      }
      if ( $line =~ m/(OK)/ ) {
            $return_type = $1;
      }
    }

    INFO ($type,$return_type);
}


    command Ouptut :

    PSLAs Latest Operation Summary
    Codes: * active, ^ inactive, ~ pending

    ID           Type        Destination       Stats       Return      Last
                                               (ms)        Code        Run
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    *1           icmp      192.168.25.14    RTT=1       OK          1 second ago
```

Comment: While you are technically "using" regular expressions you aren't really "using" their power since you are using fixed substrings as the patterns. Start here http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html for a quick tutorial.

Comment: The rest of the documentation [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) [perlreref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

Comment: (1) What is `$ipsla`? The `foreach` needs a list to iterate over -- is that an arrayref?  (2) Is the line of interest really (and always) the last line of the command output?

Comment: yes , last line of command output is what i'm looking for

Comment: OK, that makes it far simpler.  But we need to know what `$ipsla` is. It is a scalar and if it is a multi-line string I'd have to split it (by newline), if it is an arrayref I can de-reference. This is a matter of what that particular class (which you haven't specified) returns -- I don't know that. Can you clarify?

Comment: its a scalar and not not arrayref

Comment: The term "_arrayref_" is often used for a _reference_ to an array. That is a _scalar_ -- it's one value, not a collection like an array or hash.  The `$` in `$ipsla` means it's a scalar, one thing.  But what kind of a thing? It can be a string which contains newline characters, thus representing multiple lines, or a reference to an array.  It can be a number or a simple string as well, or yet other things, but that wouldn't make sense for a command output, which is normally lines of text.

Comment: You can see [`Perl variable types`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) in [`perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html), and skim through introductory parts of [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

Comment: Example.  Consider text with three lines -- `hey`, `hi`, `hello`.  We can have that in a string, like so `$text = "hey\nhi\nhello"`.  This is a _scalar_, it is one string of characters.  (When printed those `\n` induce line-breaks so it appears as multiple lines.) If we want to iterate over lines, we have to break it up -- split by `\n`.  Or, we could have `@lines = qw(hey hi hello)` and then take a _reference_ to that array by `$text = \@lines`. Or we can form it by `$text = [ ... ]`.  This `$text` is also a scalar.  To iterate over lines using that we need to _dereference_ it, by `@$text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** to some clarifications -- we need only the last line

---

As if often the case, you don't need a regex to parse the output as shown.  You have space-separated fields and can just [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the line and pick the elements you need.

We are told that the line of interest is the last line of the command output. Then we don't need the loop but can take the last element of the array with lines. It is still unclear how `$ipsla` contains the output -- as a multi-line string or perhaps as an arrayref. Since it is output of a command I'll treat it as a multi-line string, akin to what [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) returns. Then, instead of the `foreach` loop

```
my @lines = split '\n', $ipsla;      # if $ipsla is a multi-line string
# my @lines = @$ipsla;               # if $ipsla is an arrayref

pop @lines while $line[-1] !~ /\S/;  # remove possible empty lines at end

my ($type, $return_type) = (split ' ', $lines[-1])[1,4];
```

Here are some comments on the code.  Let me know if more is needed.

We can see in the shown output that the fields up to what we need have no spaces. So we can split the last line on white space, by `split ' ', $lines[-1]`, and take the 2nd and 5th element (indices 1 and 4), by `( ... )[1,4]`. These are our two needed values and we assign them.

Just in case the output ends with empty lines we first remove them, by doing `pop @lines` as long as the last line has no non-space characters, `while $lines[-1] !~ /\S/`.  That is the same as

```
while ( $lines[-1] !~ /\S/ ) { pop @lines }
```

---

*Original version, edited for clarifications. It is also a valid way to do what is needed.*

I assume that data starts after the line with only dashes. Set a flag once that line is reached, process the line(s) if the flag is set. Given the rest of your code, the loop

```
my $data_start;
foreach (@lines) 
{
    if (not $data_start) { 
        $data_start = 1 if /^\s* -+ \s*$/x;  # only dashes and optional spaces
    }
    else {
        my ($type, $return_type) = (split)[1,4];
        print "type: $type, return code: $return_type\n";
    }
}
```

This is a sketch until clarifications come. It also assumes that there are more lines than one.

Comment: If "Last Run" is of interest you might want to put a limit on your split since the field contains spaces.

Comment: @mp3 In principle, yes, good observation. However, here I go by shown data and only the last field contains spaces.  We need two of the previous fields.

Comment: @mp3 Oh, I didn't trigger on your _If "Last Run" ..._ -- sorry.  That is right, if that was needed that we'd have to do more work.  Incidentally though, we can then pick the `[5]` element -- the number from that last field! Unless it can be `2 minutes 5 seconds` or some such, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all possibilities of output from that command so my regular expression may need tweaking.

I assume the goal is to get the values of all columns in variables. I opted to store values in a hash using the column names as the hash keys. I printed the results for debugging / demonstration purposes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub check_summary {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my %results = map { ($_,undef) } qw(Code ID Type Destination Stats Return_Code Last_Run); # Put results in hash, use column names for keys, set values to undef.

    my $ipsla = $self->{ssh_obj}->exec('show ip sla');    

    foreach my $line (@$ipsla) {
        chomp $line; # Remove newlines from last field

        if($line =~ /^([*^~])([0-9]+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)\s+([[:alnum:]=]+)\s+([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s].*)$/) {
            $results{Code}        = $1; # Code prefixing ID
            $results{ID}          = $2;
            $results{Type}        = $3;
            $results{Destination} = $4;
            $results{Stats}       = $5;
            $results{Return_Code} = $6;
            $results{Last_Run}    = $7;
        }
    }

    # Testing
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper(\%results);
}

# Demonstrate
check_summary();

# Commented for testing
#INFO ($type,$return_type);
```

Worked on the submitted test line.

EDIT:
Regular expressions allow you to specify patterns instead of the exact text you are attempting to match. This is powerful but complicated at times. You need to read the Perl Regular Expression documentation to really learn them.

Perl regular expressions also allow you to capture the matched text. This can be done multiple times in a single pattern which is how we were able to capture all the columns with one expression. The matches go into numbered variables...
    $1
    $2

Comment: i belive  you didn't notice that the command output starts with the following lines. so the regular expression u specified tries to match the below lines and not the actual output that is required . the line of interest really (and always) the last line of the command output   ".PSLAs Latest Operation Summary
    Codes: * active, ^ inactive, ~ pending"

Comment: Unless I am missing something, my code is designed to match the last line of your example output and ignore the rest. Do you mean you just want to match column headers and you aren't interested in the values?